# Setup.py - Add data files inside package in setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

everyone! Jumping to my issue, I have this file structure, in Python 3.7:

```
mypackage/
 |- config/
 |---- config.json
 |- mypackage/
 |---- __init__.py
 |---- main.py
 |- docs/
 |---- __init__.py
 |---- doc_folder/
 |--------- text_file.txt
 |- setup.py
 |- MANIFEST.in
```

My setup.py is using setuptools and has, of relevance:

```
setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

And my MANIFEST.in has:

```
recursive-include config *
recursive-include docs *
```

When I either run `pip install .` or `python setup.py sdist & pip install dist/mypackage-1.0`, the same thing happens:

- When the distribution is built, the logs say both `docs` and `config` are copied into `mypackage-1.0`;
- When installed, I can't find `config`;
- When installed, `docs` is found in the site-packages folder (`site-packages/docs`).
- If i add an __init__.py to `config`, it also appears in the site-packages folder.
  My objective would be to have `docs` and `config` inside of the `mypackage` directory, because I'm afraid if I pip install different projects with config folders, they're going to override each other. It'll also be more useful to do relative imports, I assume.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Move both `config` and `doc` dirs under `mypackage` (the one that is actually a package,  containing an `__init__.py`).

Comment: @hoefling, feel free to write it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer, if you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving both `config` and `doc` dirs under `mypackage` (the one that is actually a package, containing an `__init__.py`) should fix the issue. The changed directory structure from the question:

```
mypackage/
├── mypackage/
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── config/
|   |   └── config.json
|   ├── docs/
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   └── doc_folder/
|   |       └── text_file.txt
|   └── main.py
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in
```